# Using bash script, How to add a comment in the beginning of each file to all files in a folder

Tags: bash, file, shell, unix

How do i Add a comment  in the beginning of each file with file name the folder name. Need to do this to all files in a folder

eg:
directory:Chapter01
Files: file1_1

**Sample inpput:**

```
cat file1_1
hello hello hello
```

**Expected output:**

```
cat file1_1
####Directory Name:Chapter01, File Name: file1_1
hello hello hello
```

Answer (score 1):

This untested snippet should work.

```
for i in *
do
  echo "Processing ${i}" 
  echo "Directory Name:$(pwd), File name:${i}" > ${i}.tmp
  cat ${i} >> ${i}.tmp
  echo "Created ${i}"
  # mv ${i}.tmp ${i}
done
```

This will create a `.tmp` corresponding to each file in your directory. The commented out `mv` will change the original file. You can do that if you're happy with the results.

Comment: You would probably want `mv -f ${i}.tmp ${i}` if you wanted to avoid a reluctance to overwrite the existing files without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{n=split(FILENAME, a, "/"); 
  print "# Dir name: " a[n-1] " File name: " a[n] > FILENAME} 
  {print > FILENAME}' path/to/files/*
```

as a side benefit, it will skip empty files.  It will print the immediate parent directory "files" and the actual filename.  You need to run at least one dir up.

Answer (score 0):

Use an editor to change the current files.

```
dirname=${PWD##*/}
for file in inp*; do
        ed -s "${file}" <<EOF >/dev/null
1
a
####Directory Name:${dirname}, File Name: ${file}
.
w
q
EOF
done
```